# {"code":401,"message":"Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."} - Symfony 5.0 - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle

Tags: postgresql, symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use Synfony 5.0 and "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.6".

displays the following message:
{"code":401,"message":"Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."}

This error only occurs with postgres. When I switch to mysql it works.
How can I solve this?

Below is my security.yaml:

```
security:
  encoders:        
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
  firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false        

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator 

    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider       


  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }`
```

in the log:

Mar 30 10:19:51 |WARN | SERVER POST (401) /api/login_check host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="127.0.0.1" scheme="https"
[2020-03-30T10:19:51.769724-03:00] request.INFO: Matched route "api_login_check". {"route":"api_login_check","route_parameters":{"_route":"api_login_check"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check","method":"POST"} []
[2020-03-30T10:19:51.888870-03:00] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["my_username"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS...\n ^ at C:\Projetos\Projetos\mp\vendor\symfony\security-core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:96)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["wagner"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS...\n ^ at C:\Projetos\Projetos\mp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php:60)\n[previous exception]
[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 42703): SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS...\n ^ at C:\Projetos\Projetos\mp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:123)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42703): SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS...\n ^ at C:\Projetos\Projetos\mp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:121)"} []

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which parts of that error message are unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by changing the name of the User class, because in Postgres the word "user" is reserved and there is an error in the query interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the User class name.